# Property of Medians and Cirumcircle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a non-isosceles triangle. Medians of $\triangle ABC$ intersect the circumcircle in points $L,M,N$. If $L$ lies on the median of $BC$ and $LM=LN$, then prove that $2a^2=b^2+c^2$.

**My Attempt:**

[image]

Let $G$ be the centroid of $\triangle ABC$ and $D$ be the mid-point of $BC$.

Since $LM=LN$, therefore $LM$ and $LN$ will subtend equal angles on the circumference of circumcircle

$\Rightarrow \angle GBL=\angle LCG$

$GL=GL$

Altitude of $\triangle BGL$ from $B$ to $GL$=Altitude of $\triangle LGC$ from $C$ to $GL$

Area($\triangle BGL$)=Area($\triangle LGC$)

Now, based on this ,**can it be said that $\square GBLC$ is a parallelogram.** If yes then

$$DL=GD=\frac{m_{a}}{3}$$

$\Rightarrow AD.DG=BD.DC$

$$m_{a}.\frac{m_{a}}{3}=\frac{a^2}{4}$$

$\Rightarrow 4m^2_{a}=3a^2$

$\Rightarrow 2b^2+2c^2-a^2=3a^2$

$\Rightarrow b^2+c^2=2a^2$

I am not sure whether this justification is sufficient(the one that I have written in bold). What more can be added to seal the issue

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Consider $\triangle AGB$ and $\triangle MGL$

$$\angle BGA=\angle LGM$$

$$\angle GAB=\angle GML$$

$$\triangle AGB \sim \triangle MGL$$

$$\frac{GB}{GL}=\frac{AG}{GM}=\frac{AB}{LM}$$

$$AG=\frac{c}{LM}GM$$

[image]

Similarly $\triangle AGC \sim \triangle NGL$

$$\frac{AG}{GN}=\frac{GC}{LG}=\frac{AC}{LN}$$

$$AG=\frac{b}{LN}GN$$

Thus$$AG=\frac{b}{LN}GN=\frac{c}{LM}GM$$
$$\Rightarrow c.GM=b.NG$$

Also, we have $$BG.GM=CG.GN$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{2}{3}m_{b}.GM=\frac{2}{3}m_{c}.NG$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{2}{3}m_{b}.\frac{b}{c}.NG=\frac{2}{3}m_{c}.NG$$

$$\Rightarrow b.m_{b}=c.m_{c}$$

$$\Rightarrow b\sqrt{2c^2+2a^2-b^2}=c\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}$$

$$\Rightarrow 2b^2c^2+2a^2b^2-b^4=2a^2c^2+2b^2c^2-c^4$$

$$\Rightarrow 2a^2(b^2-c^2)=b^4-c^4$$

$$\Rightarrow 2a^2=b^2+c^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\measuredangle LAC=\alpha_1$, $\measuredangle LAB=\alpha_2$, $\measuredangle MBA=\beta_1$, $\measuredangle MBC=\beta_2$, $\measuredangle NCB=\gamma_1$ and $\measuredangle NCA=\gamma_2$.

Thus,
$$\gamma_1+\alpha_2=\measuredangle NBM+\measuredangle BML=\measuredangle NML=\measuredangle MNL=\measuredangle MNC+\measuredangle LNC=\beta_2+\alpha_1,$$
which gives
$$\cos(\gamma_1+\alpha_2)=\cos(\beta_2+\alpha_1)$$ or 
$$\cos\gamma_1\cos\alpha_2-\sin\gamma_1\sin\alpha_2=\cos\beta_2\cos\alpha_1-\sin\beta_2\sin\alpha_1$$ or by law of cosines and by law of sines
$$\frac{a^2+m_c^2-\frac{c^2}{4}}{2am_c}\cdot\frac{c^2+m_a^2-\frac{a^2}{4}}{2cm_a}-\frac{\frac{c}{2}\sin\beta}{m_c}\cdot\frac{\frac{a}{2}\sin\beta}{m_a}=$$
$$=\frac{a^2+m_b^2-\frac{b^2}{4}}{2am_b}\cdot\frac{b^2+m_a^2-\frac{a^2}{4}}{2bm_a}-\frac{\frac{b}{2}\sin\gamma}{m_b}\cdot\frac{\frac{a}{2}\sin\gamma}{m_a}$$ or
$$\frac{\left(a^2+\frac{1}{4}(2a^2+2b^2-c^2)-\frac{c^2}{4}\right)\left(c^2+\frac{1}{4}(2b^2+2c^2-a^2)-\frac{a^2}{4}\right)}{acm_c}-\frac{ac\sin^2\beta}{m_c}=$$
$$=\frac{\left(a^2+\frac{1}{4}(2a^2+2c^2-b^2)-\frac{b^2}{4}\right)\left(b^2+\frac{1}{4}(2b^2+2c^2-a^2)-\frac{a^2}{4}\right)}{abm_b}-\frac{ab\sin^2\gamma}{m_b}$$ or
$$\frac{(3a^2+b^2-c^2)(3c^2+b^2-a^2)}{4acm_c}-\frac{ac\left(\frac{2S}{ac}\right)^2}{m_c}=$$
$$=\frac{(3a^2+c^2-b^2)(3b^2+c^2-a^2)}{4abm_b}-\frac{ab\left(\frac{2S}{ab}\right)^2}{m_b}$$ or 
$$\frac{(3a^2+b^2-c^2)(3c^2+b^2-a^2)-\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}{cm_c}=$$
$$=\frac{(3a^2+c^2-b^2)(3b^2+c^2-a^2)-\sum\limits_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}{bm_b}$$ or
$$\frac{a^4+c^4-b^4-4a^2c^2}{c\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}}=\frac{a^4+b^4-c^4-4a^2b^2}{b\sqrt{2a^2+2c^2-b^2}}$$ or
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2(b^2+c^2-2a^2)(b^2-c^2)(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)=0$$ and we are done!

Comment: Can we not use similarity of triangles. If we are able to show that triangle AGB is similar to triangle MGL and triangle AGC is similar to triangle NGL then we may be able to reach some conclusion.